# How can I convert my half-log cabin's floating (poles on rika blocks) foundation to in-ground cemented poles?

Tags: concrete, wood, foundation, replacement

My wooden house is a 6m x 6m CCA treated frame, cladded with CCA treated half-log. From the back to the front, there is about 1m of fall. The house rests on CCA gum poles in the front, where it is 1m high & directly on rika blocks in the rear. Both poles and rika blocks rest on the ground, ie: there is no part of the foundation underground. The house sits on the earth like a table on a floor.

My common sense drives me to think that I need to convert this foundation to in-ground and cemented. However, I cannot visualise or find information on how this can be done while the cabin is in use.

One idea is to add proper brick pillars between current poles. Then reinforce by attaching the house frame to the pillars. When all the floating wooden poles have brick pillars between them.

What would you do in this situation, if the house is currently lived in?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: If you can not visualize guess how hard it is for us with no pictures, it may not be a real problem at all just that you need to stabilize the soil in the area of the pilings/blocks.

Comment: If "rain is washing away around your blocks" **under your building** you need to **correct the grade** around your building so that surface water does not flow through the foundation area. That's immensely less expensive than replacing the foundation under it. One option that is often less expensive than replacing the foundation under the building is to build the new foundation to one side, without a building in the way, then have the building moved onto it. But you probably don't need a new foundation at all, if you correct the grading.

Comment: Fair point, @Ecnerwal. However, I just drove past (again) a house on the river bank near me. About 2/3 of the house is supported by concrete piles while the ground underneath it slopes significantly down the river bank to the river below. There's probably 20-30 feet elevation change between the front of the property and the river bank. Of course, this house was explicitly designed & built for these conditions... In general, I'd agree with you.

Comment: @Ecnerwal - Your idea seems like a solution to me in terms of managing the water flow, and gradient modifications. Once that is done, I may only need to perform minor work on replacing one pole at a time with a slightly 'planted' version. Easier, simpler. Thanks, I wish I could upvote your comment.

Thanks everyone else, I realise that my words did not visualise well. I edited the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

Get professionals.

Jacking a building is not a do it yourself job.  If not done right will end with a wreck building with the possibility of you being under it(it ruins your day/life).

It sounds like professionals were not involved with the plans for the building in that area to begin with, if rain is washing away the supporting ground.

Comment: Thanks. I agree with regards to getting professionals. We did have a professional company build and erect it, which is what scares me. With the right idea in mind, I can have the knowledge to guide/see through the mud if more pro's like these guys show up. Appreciate your reply.